# Fetch SVG element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, d3.js, svg

I want to fetch an `svg` element using jQuery. Following is the code to fetch the element:

```
var svgHtml = $("#graphHolder svg");
```

But the problem is while executing this, it's taking time to fetch the `svg` element and code is running ahead. As a result, I am getting value of `svgHtml` as empty object.

Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: Do you wanna go with jQuery? On svg d3 is the best option for any manipulation. Use d3.select('#divid') this will help you

Comment: *"it's taking time to fetch the svg element and code is running ahead."* — this is most likely not the correct interpretation of the empty result. There seems to be more to it than meets the eye. Please share some more code to get proper help.

Comment: @altocumulus is correct.  `svgHtml` being "empty" is not an `async` problem, but rather an incorrect selector.

Comment: @altocumulus Below is the html which I am referring to:                        <span id="graphHolder">
 <svg id="plot" width="725" height="535">
  <g transform="translate(100,20)">
   <clipPath id="clip">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="605" height="465">
   </clipPath>
  </g>
 </svg>
</span>                                                                                                             Please suggest me the way to fetch entire DOM element using jQuery

Comment: @Pooja Given the code you provided, the query from your question should return the desired result. Your problem, however, is still not reproducible. Please have a look at [ask] and how to provide a [mcve]. Especially setting up a running demo will get your question much more attention and raise the chances of getting help.